# How to create an m3u playlist containing mp3 and m4a files?

Tags: mp3, m4a

how can I create a .m3u playlist file with `.mp3` and `.m4a` files in it using debian linux please?

I tried this but the end-result is non-playable `ls -w 1 *.m4a *.mp3> ~/.mpd/playlists/beeb-radio.m3u`.

It lists all the files with the correct extensions but when I try to load it in MPD, it says that the song is non-playable.

Answer (score 1):

The source directory is ~/Music/beeb-radio/ 
and the target directory is ~/.mpd/playlists

and the relevant code is -

```
cd ~/Music 
ls -1 beeb-radio/*.{mp3,m4a} > ~/.mpd/playlists/beeb-radio.m3u'
```

This creates the file 'beeb-radio.m3u' which is instantly playable by MPD if put into its playlist directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [`mkpl`](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/mkpl) tool.

For your purpose the command is like this:

```
mkpl -d beeb-radio/ -a -r -f mp3 m4a ~/.mpd/playlists/beeb-radio.m3u
```

`-d` or `--directories` -> Directories that contains multimedia files

`-f` or `--format`  -> Select only a file format

`-a` or `--absolute` -> Absolute file name

`-r` or `--recursive` -> Recursive search

`~/.mpd/playlists/beeb-radio.m3u` -> playlist file

Comment: It is more robust way to compose a playlist. Howerver, it can be done without any tool.

Comment: The answer is OK, but there is more simple solution.